# Entity framework 6 - Get Entity with ICollection<ChildEntities> but only return entities which satisfy a specific condition in child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to filter by the following

- Each *Car* has N *Wheels* attached, each type of *Wheel* has its own price
- I get a request with an array of the types o *Wheels* I want to consider in a *Car* entity.
- I want to retrieve only the *Cars* which has *Wheels* within the requested ID, but only return the *Cars* when that requested Id happens to be the *Wheel* of minimum price attached to the Car
- Basically I want to answer the question "Give me the Cars , which has attached wheels of the type requested, but only when the type of wheel requested corresponds to the one of less price inside the Car".

My problems is, that despite working, it is performing too slow. Do you know another approach?

Models - Relation between Car and Wheels is N to N

```cs
public class RequestDto
{
    public int IdWheelType { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WheelCar> Wheels { get; set; }
}

public class WheelCar
{
    public int IdCar { get; set; }
    public int IdWheel { get; set; }
    public Car IdCarNavigation { get; set; }
    public Wheel IdWheelNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class Wheel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price{ get; set; } //the best price corresponds to the minimum value
}
```

Query -

```cs
IQueryable<Cars> carsQuery= _dbContext.Cars;  
    
query = query.Where(x =>
        x.Wheels.Any(y =>
        y.IdWheel== == request.IdWheelType &&
        y.IdWheel== x.Wheels.FirstOrDefault(z => z.IdWheelNavigation.Price== x.Wheels.Min(u => u.IdWheelNavigation.Price)).IdWheel));

// more filters come here, that's why I need an IQueryable<Cars>. 
// I don't mind the content of ICollection<WheelCar> once they have been filtered
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and less complicated if you put `Car` and `Wheel` in one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Os not possible is a N to N relation

Comment: I think you have a typo in the query. See if you can fix and update.

Comment: @atiyar please chekc now. The request it is only one Id of wheel

Comment: Ok, so you want all the cars that match the wheel id in the request, but I really didn't understand the `minimum priority` part. Could you simplify that a bit?

Comment: @atiyar check now, i changed the model a little bit. With price is more understable. The question is "Give me the Cars , which has attached wheels of the type requested, but only when the type of wheel requested corresponds to the one of less price inside the Car"

Comment: Lets say the `Id` in request is 4, and you found 10 cars in database which has wheel with `Id` 4. Now which cars from this 10 you want to select/return? A wheel with `Id` has a single price value. So, how do you compare the price?

Comment: @atiyar only the cars which has wheel 4 and it is the cheapest one of the wheels

Comment: "_and it is the cheapest one of the wheels_" - do you mean the cheapest one among the four wheels of the car?

Comment: @atiyar yes that’s it